# Returning the file contents

Tags: php

When I have a php file that looks like this (no scripts, just returning values):

`return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`

I have to use `require` or `include` to get those file contents like this:

```
$contents = require "data.php";
```

Is this this the common way to get data out of a file or can it be done in more ways?

Comment: It's only common if the "data" is executable code, in which case it's very common

Comment: @MarkBaker What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that `return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` is executable code, it is a script (not that it does a great deal besides returning an array of values, but it is an executable script and therefore can be included/required which will then execute the code contained in the file

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm sorry for my late response, but what's "non-executable" code then? Because I would think that returning some values isn't really exutable. Also, can you edit that in an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: A file that contained `<?php return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` would be executable code; a file that contained `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` would be non-executable code.... there's no code statements for PHP to execute. Using `include` or `require` on a file that contained the latter wouldn't achieve anything; you'd need to use `file_get_contents()` (or similar) to read the actual data into a variable

Comment: @MarkBaker That sounds pretty logical, thank you :) Can you please edit it into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MarkBaker posted in the comments:

It's only common if the "data" is executable code, in which case it's very common.

A file that contained `<?php return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` would be executable code; a file that contained `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` would be non-executable code. There's no code statements for PHP to execute.

Using `include` or `require` on a file that contained the latter wouldn't achieve anything; you'd need to use `file_get_contents()` (or similar) to read the actual data into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

For real, this way I see first time, and can I ask you, this works? Anyway, it's not a good practice. It's better to describe function in file, and then use function.

data.php:

```
function get_array(){
    return [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5];
}
```

and then use it like:

```
include('data.php');
$contents = get_array();
```

If you want, to get all file content as string, you can use file_get_contents:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('data.php');
```

And what's difference between include and require? When you use include, and file doesn't exists, you dont't get fatal error.

Comment: Yeah, it works. I've been using it quiet alot. But i like it. :P

Comment: If it works, why didn't you accept it as the answer?

Comment: @Mawg Because it's not really the solution for me. I dont like it